# React widget created from webpack and create-react-app exposes only a webpackJsonpclient

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a react app that was created from create-react-app (lets call it APP-1) which I need to use in another web app owned by a different team. The agreed up approach was to bundle the React app as a library and deploy it to a CDN and use it on the other project via a script tag.

I did the following.
1. Created a webpack.config.js file in root (did not eject from CRA) and used the following config.

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'bundle.js': glob
       .sync('build/static/?(js|css)/?(main|2).*.?(js|css)')
       .map(f => path.resolve(__dirname, f)),
     },
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    library: 'APP-1',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
 module: {
   rules: [
   {
     test: /\.css$/,
     use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
   },
 ],
 },
};
```

The entry reads off the bundled js (main.js and 2.hash.js) and css files generated by running npm run build (CRA command). The idea is to combine them into a single file which is then output as a lib.

The generated bundle is then loaded onto a CDN and that is added as the source for a script tag in the other project. Now, in the other project I am able to access the 'APP-1' namespace on the window object - but weirdly it only exposes the webpackJsonpclient object.

eg: console.log("module: ", APP-1) or console.log(window.APP-1)

[image]

Not sure what is going on or how to approach debugging this. The following is the index.js file

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from 'react-dom';
import { App } from './App';

//ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

export const init = () => {
  console.log('THIS IS FROM THE APP-1 APP');
  return {
    mount() {
      const el = document.getElementById('app-1');
      render(<App />, el);
    },
    unmount() {
      const el = document.getElementById('app-1');
      if (el) unmountComponentAtNode(el);
    },
  };
};
```

One approach would be to eject out of CRA and configure webpack such that it builds the library. I was hoping if there was anyway to do it without ejecting. Thanks for all your help!

Docs that I followed:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary (For webpack lib configs)
https://selleo.com/blog/how-to-create-embedded-react-widget (For creating the react widget).
Thanks